# Why PostgreSQL does so hard plan for simple query?

Tags: performance, postgresql, query-planner

I have a 25mln rows "Zemla" table with index

```
CREATE INDEX zemla_level
  ON public."Zemla"
  USING btree
  (level);
```

Now I do simple query

```
select * from "Zemla" where level = 7
```

and get very hard query plan

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on "Zemla"  (cost=18316.26..636704.15 rows=978041 width=181) (actual time=216.681..758.663 rows=975247 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (level = 7)
  Heap Blocks: exact=54465
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on zemla_level  (cost=0.00..18071.74 rows=978041 width=0) (actual time=198.041..198.041 rows=1949202 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (level = 7)
```

and another simple query which should be executed immediately when index present i think

```
select count(*) from "Zemla" where level = 7

Aggregate  (cost=639149.25..639149.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1188.366..1188.366 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "Zemla"  (cost=18316.26..636704.15 rows=978041 width=0) (actual time=213.918..763.833 rows=975247 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (level = 7)
        Heap Blocks: exact=54465
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on zemla_level  (cost=0.00..18071.74 rows=978041 width=0) (actual time=195.409..195.409 rows=1949202 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (level = 7)
```

My question is why PostgreSQL after first Index Scan does another Bitmap Heap Scan with so much overhead ?

Edit: [What is a "Bitmap heap scan" in a query plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592626/what-is-a-bitmap-heap-scan-in-a-query-plan) is another question because it answers why some queries with OR operator has bitmap heap scan. My queries haven't neither OR nor AND operator

Comment: What do you mean with "hard plan"? show us the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze)` instead a plain explain.

Comment: fixed question body to explain (analyze)

Comment: The row estimates are quite off. Does running `vacuum analyze "Zemla"` change anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "Bitmap heap scan" in a query plan?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592626/what-is-a-bitmap-heap-scan-in-a-query-plan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the bitmap Heap Scan is the algorithm fetching the data from the disk. It analyses all the disk-pages the engine has to fetch and sort them for minimal hard-drive head movement.

It takes time because your table must be very large and maybe highly fragmented on the disk.

---

For your second query `count(*)`, PostgreSQL will still need to read the resulting rows to verify that they exist; other database systems may only need to reference the index in this situation. Check this page for more information:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans

---

Try a `VACCUM FULL` on the table, and see if it speeds things up.